# Html table, how do it two tr in one line?

Tags: html, html-table

I have table and for row I add data-href, but I have for each row drop down and for this fro down don't need link, how to do it ?

in this variant my drop down not work because when click him call data-href

```
        <tr class="clickable" data-href="{{ path('outbound_invoices_show', {'id': outboundInvoice.id}) }}">
            <td>
                {{ outboundInvoice.invoiceNumber }}
            </td>
            <td>
                 my drop down with link
            </td>
        </tr>
```

in this variant work fine but have two row

```
            <tr class="clickable" data-href="{{ path('outbound_invoices_show', {'id': outboundInvoice.id}) }}">
            <td>
                {{ outboundInvoice.invoiceNumber }}
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                 my drop down with link
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
table{width: 100%} tr{display: inline}
```

Should work. Otherwise please show what you've got. You could also use ul as inline list instead, as I believe rows are not supposed to be inline by default.

Comment: how to create first tr dynamic and second dynamic in one line?

Comment: You want your `<tr>`s to be in one line?